# IIS crashes and restarts without dropping a mini-dump

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windbg

I have a tough scenario I'm trying to debug...  On a web forms page, when I click submit, the web server hits some error and restarts the w3svc process.

I do not see any stack trace dumped to the event log.  The only entry in the Windows Application Log is:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
>
> Exception code: 0xe053534f

There is no mini dump created for me to attach windbg to...

Any ideas how to debug my issue?

Comment: I suspect it's a stackoverflow. Can you debug into the button click handler, step into the code and see if the stack is getting deeper and deeper?

Comment: When I run locally with my VS2010 install, I do not get the problem described.  However, my QA team can get it pretty regularly...  so I am attempting to debug with WinDBG.   I am attempting to debug as you suggested...

Comment: check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619093/running-my-web-site-in-a-32-bit-application-pool-on-a-64-bit-os] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619093/running-my-web-site-in-a-32-bit-application-pool-on-a-64-bit-os)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you make a loop call like

```
public string sMyText
{
   get {return sMyText;}
   set {sMyText = value;}
}
```

and you call the sMyText

or something like

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

or something like

```
Server.Transfer("TheSamePage.aspx");
```

In this cases the crash is not call the minidump.
Can you run the [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and see if your pool is eat the cpu until is crash ?

Comment: Similar...  I found the problem to be a call to Page.Validate() from within a private method that was being called by a Validator attached to a web control

Answer (score 1):

To create a memory dump for a crashing application, you can use either DebugDiag or adplus. Either will monitor the process, and generate a dump file when the crash occurs.  DebugDiag can also analyze dump files and generate an issue report (similar to the "!analyze -v" command in WinDbg.)

DebugDiag can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en).

You should find adplus installed with the Debugging Tools for Windows - which is the same installer that contains WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [Procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd99690) to get a memory dump when the process
terminates and look for exception and call-stack.

> -t    Write a dump when the process terminates.

FYI...what you see in EventViewer is `Watson buckets` which tells which application and module had an unhandled exception. From your log it looks like `kernelBase`was the faulting module.