# How to restart an ASP.Net Application automatically when it goes down

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have developed a asp.net application which is deployed on his personal server. The application is running in the background and updating his e-commerce database automatically. I have used Quartz.net for scheduling purpose.

**My problem is that the application gets stopped after certain period (3-8 hours) of time.**

I want a way to restart the application automatically as soon as it goes down.OR alternatively a service which visit the application periodically so it goes live.

Note: I have access to my client server and can yous windows scheduling if there is any solution relatively.

I have also read similar post but had no luck.

Your prompt response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why is stopped ? do you have too many errors maybe that bring it down ?

Comment: There is no error reported while stopping.

Comment: don't you know why is stopping ? And one more, what is stop, the pool, or the specific site ?

Comment: The pool doesn't get stop because there are other sites in the same pool and running well. The specific site is down only.

Comment: Use this answer to first find the reason that is stop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499791/application-crashing-due-to-stackoverflow  then maybe you can find a solution by updating the question. To send message to auto start every minute is not going to solve your problems

Comment: @Aristos: I read that referred link but I couldn't understand the accepted example as I am new to programming and need more information as where to put the code and how to get the result. Your co-operation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is the global.asax, and there is the ` Application_End`. Inside `Application_End` you use the code on the answer, get the strings, and log them somewhere. This strings tells you why the application stops.

Comment: Oops its in C# while I am using VB.Net. I tried to convert to VB version using some websites but there is some problem in the last two lines saying "Expression is not a method". Any help please.