# Fatal Error when running asp.net 3.5 application in windows 2008 server R2

Tags: .net-3.5

My asp.net application causes this error when hosted in a IIS 7.0 environment on windows server 2008 R2 machine. However the code works fine in my local system.

Error 1:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5446 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEF9E040D2) (80131506
```

Error 2:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.5446, time stamp: 0x4d8cdb54
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000006baa29
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

Can some one please help me on this!!!

Comment: Make sure you are not building your asp.net in .net framework 3.5 and trying to run/deploy it in .net framework 2.0 (your post headline says 3.5 but your error 1 message says .net runtime ver 2.0). Also, check this link about running a .net framwork 2.0 app under a user account context when no user profile is associated with it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384

Comment: open ur project in visual studio, check its property,there u'll find framework version.
Now check if some pool is there to run that particular version in ur iis administration window.
If no then create one otherwise try to port ur code to another version by selecting the framework in property tab.

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues on these links which can help you trace down the problem using `Windows Error Reporting` and `Check your System Logs`.

http://blog.whitesites.com/Debugging-Faulting-Application-w3wp-exe-Crashes__634424707278896484_blog.htm

http://forums.iis.net/p/1182629/2000234.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/171b1b3f-e70f-4e4e-bdbc-f33ddb0e7972/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/9be88a2f-c8cc-4a73-9371-45ab73982123

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=111541

If there is some OS version issue then use this previous question here:
[Running my web site in a 32-bit application pool on a 64-bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619093/running-my-web-site-in-a-32-bit-application-pool-on-a-64-bit-os)

Hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

What is your application's framework. if it is v2, try rebuild with v4. if it is v4, change iis settings. if it is v4 and your server doesn't support v4, it crashes. also if it is server 2008 r2, you should work with iis 7.5. I think it is framework error. please be spesific about your server and development computer settings.